# SQL query: help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need help with a sql query, I have tried to replicate my actual problem by creating this simple example:

Parents table:

```
id   name     parent_id
1   parent1     null
2   parent2     1
3   parent3     1
4   parent4     3
5   parent5     3
6   parent6     5
7   parent7     5
```

Relatives table:

```
id    name       parent_id
1   relative1   2
2   relative2   3
3   relative3   4
4   relative4   5
5   relative5   7
```

Parents table has a list of parents which also have parents themselves.
Relatives table has a list of relatives with a parent_id column.

How would I find all the relatives of parent3 including all the 'desendants' of parent3, i.e. the query should return the following from the Relatives table:

relative2 (because the parent id is 3)

relative3 (because the parent id is 4 whose parent id is 3)

relative4 (because the parent id is 5 whose parent id is 3)

relative5 (because the parent id is 7 whose parent id is 5 whose parent id is 3)

I'm using SQL Server 2008.
Hope that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is common case of recursion. You should be able to find lot of similar examples in google. Hints: learn more about recursion and CTE and you will be able to knock it down. If you still have any issues create a sqlfiddle and post your question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT [id], [name] FROM  Parents WHERE [name] = 'parent3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.[id], T1.[name] FROM CTE c 
    INNER JOIN  Parents T1 ON c.[id] = T1.[parent_id]
)

SELECT * FROM Relatives 
WHERE [parent_id] IN (SELECT [id] FROM CTE)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b2e9/1)

Comment: Perfect example, now I'm just trying to understand it, is this correct:
The first select gives id = 3 and name = parent3 from Parents.
The second select statement gets id and name from Parent where parent_id = 3, which gives me id and name of row 4 and 5.
This is the part where I'm a bit unsure, what happens next; does the second result set 'replace' the first one and then the second select runs again looking for data from Parents where id is 4 or 5.
Then the second select runs again using the id from each successive result set.
It continues until the select does not return any values.